# I can't connect to my Scala implementation of a web socket server, running on my home machine. How can I troubleshoot this?

Tags: python, scala, sockets, websocket, network-programming

I'm running the server code on my home machine.
This is how my server code starts. The "a" is printed out but "b" never prints.

```
import java.io._
import java.net._
...
val portNumber = 9999
val serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber)
println("a")
val clientSocket = serverSocket.accept()
println("b")
```

Here is my Python client code I'm running on an AWS server.

```
import socket
# create an INET, STREAMing socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# now connect to the web server
s.connect(("88.112.131.235", 9999))
```

I got the IP address by Googling for "What is my IP?"

Comment: Try connecting via the LAN IP rather than what google tells you (the WAN) IP. Your router almost certainly isn't setup to either forward the port, or loopback the connection internally. This presumes you are at 'home'

Comment: Seems a bit strange to run the server at home and the client on AWS. Should be the other way round; then you wouldn't need to worry about your IP address or forwarding the port.

Comment: @user3788685 I don't think the LAN IP is working :( Did you notice that I'm running the server on Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud?

Comment: Sorry no I didn't notice that - in which case you need to check that the server end at 'home' has the router set to forward the correct port etc - do your local connection checks before trying to check from the cloud. But as Daniel says above you should really switch it round so the server component is in the cloud.

Comment: @user3788685 You think there is no way to get this working without messing with the router?

Comment: Without a doubt. Unless you do the port forwarding etc on the router you will *never* reach the Scala socket from the outside. Sorry